# segmentation fault on g_string_truncate ()?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, glib

When trying the following in C :

```
g_string_printf(qbuf,"INSERT INTO inbox (number, smsdate, text) VALUES ('%s','%04d-%02d-%02d %02d:%02d:%02d', '%s')",
          xmx.remote.number,
          xmx.smsc_time.year,
          xmx.smsc_time.month,
          xmx.smsc_time.day,
          xmx.smsc_time.hour,
          xmx.smsc_time.minute,
          xmx.smsc_time.second,
          xmx.user_data[0].u.text);
```

I see the following crash:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00984809 in g_string_truncate () from /lib/libglib-2.0.so.0
(gdb)
```

Why would this happen? Is there any initiation before calling g_string_printf() ?

From frame 2:

```
(gdb) frame 2
#2  0x08049ba8 in fetching_phone (unit=0x807cd80) at main.c:152
152           g_string_printf(qbuf,"INSERT INTO inbox (number, smsdate, text) VALUES ('%s','%04d-%02d-%02d %02d:%02d:%02d', '%s')",
(gdb) ptype xmx.remote.number
type = char [40]
(gdb) ptype xmx.smsc_time.year
type = int
(gdb) ptype xmx.smsc_time.month
type = int
(gdb) ptype xmx.smsc_time.day
type = int
(gdb) ptype xmx.smsc_time.hour
type = int
(gdb) ptype xmx.smsc_time.minute
type = int
(gdb) ptype xmx.smsc_time.second
type = int
(gdb) ptype xmx.user_data[0].u.text
type = unsigned char [1601]
(gdb)
```

But, I still can't find where the problem is.

Comment: What is g_string_printf? id xmx.remote.number a String?

Comment: @bmargulies: he's talking about `glib`: http://developer.gimp.org/api/2.0/glib/glib-Strings.html

Comment: How are `qbuf` and `xmx` declared/defined? how are you initializing `qbuf`? We'll probably need some more information and code to be able to assist any.

Comment: Please just edit / update your question in the future if you'd like to provide additional information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you initialize `qbuf`?

```
GString *qbuf = g_string_new("");
```

Answer (score 2):

You probably have a bad pointer for the '%s' fields.
As you are running gdb, here is what you can do:

```
(gdb) bt
...trace...
# see the frame # of your call to g_string_printf()
(gdb) frame 5 # considering it was 5
(gdb) print xmx.remote.number
(gdb) print xmx.user_data[0].u.text
(gdb) print *xmx.remote.number
(gdb) print *xmx.user_data[0].u.text
```

or you can also check types (is `xmx.remote.number` a pointer ?)

```
(gdb) ptype xmx.remote.number
```